# Pandas get value out of list and create new list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list with filmgenres and a id, also I have a second list just with the id. I now try to use the first list to get only the genres in a list. The problem should be easy, but I couldn't find the solution.

The list with the filmgenres is loaded via an csv file. It looks like:

```
   Unnamed: 0     id                name
0            0     28              Action
1            1     12           Adventure
2            2     16           Animation
3            3     35              Comedy
4            4     80               Crime
5            5     99         Documentary
6            6     18               Drama
7            7  10751              Family
8            8     14             Fantasy
9            9     36             History
10          10     27              Horror
```

The second list is like:

```
 filmgenre = [28, 16, 14, 99]
```

My code so far:

```
filmgenreslist = pd.read_csv("genrelist.csv") #load csv
cleanfilmlist = filmgenreslist.loc[:,"name"] #tried to reduce the list to necessary informations
filmgenre = [28, 16, 14, 878]
filmgenrenames = [] #tried to save the genres for later
number = 0 #just to test
test = cleanfilmlist.loc[filmgenreslist["id"] == filmgenre[number]] #try to extract only the genrename
print(test)
#print(test[-1]) 
#to loop through the data, multiple tries but can't solve
for number in range(5):
    try:
        #filmgenrenames.append([cleanfilmlist["name"].where(cleanfilmlist["id"] == filmgenre[number])])
        filmgenrenames.append([cleanfilmlist.loc(cleanfilmlist["id"] == filmgenre[number])])
        #filmgenrenames.append([cleanfilmlist.loc[filmgenreslist["id"] == filmgenre[number]]])
        #print(number, filmgenrenames)
    except:
        filmgenrenames.append(["missing"])

print(filmgenrenames)
```

I tired to get a output like:

```
filmgenresname =["Action","Animation","Fantasy","Documentary","missing"]
```

Comment: add expected output in your question

Comment: Nils, can you simplify the question in a cleaner way? What is the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make dictionary for id as key and name as value and then map it with list:

```
map_id_name = dict(zip(filmgenreslist['id'], filmgenreslist['name']))
list(map(lambda x:map_id_name.get(x, "missing"), filmgenre ))
```